# java spring rabbitMQ send to many queues

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

My program receives a request, then gets data from it, and, depending on the data received, should send Y requests to other services (external), then should collect results from all those services and make a decision which response to send back. Please tell, is it effective to use rabbitMQ, I mean spring amqp rabbit? I have a fixed number of mentioned external services (X), I think it`s logical to have X queues in rabbit, and on every request the system will send a message to any Y queues, Y<=X, it`s not required to send messages to all queues. So I think I will have one big queue for incoming requests, and X queues for communication with external services. What do you think? How to implement it in spring amqp? May be there is a way how to do it more effective? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that patter what you looking for is called [`Scatter-Gather`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#scatter-gather).
It allows you to send a message to several recipients and wait a correlated and aggregated reply from them. With RabbitMQ you can achieve `distribution` part with [`FanoutExchange`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html), when you just send message to it and any binded queue will receive it. You should use `fixed reply queue` in that case to receive replies from consumers.

HTH

Comment: Thank you, but the number of queues may be different. For request1 I will need 5 queues, for request2 may be two or one. Please tell, why use fixed reply queue for receiving replies? Why not just use BaseOutputWrapper o=getRabbitService().sendAndCollect(w); directly there? It will be in separate thread, so I don`t think it will reduce performance.

Comment: As you wish. My idea was about a responsibility shifting to the RabbitMQ and its  FanoutExchange. The fixed `replyQueue` allows you to gather results from those services and do some required logic only in the single place. That's why I called that `Scatter-Gather`.